# how to loop through the table values in jquery from textbox

Tags: jquery

i want to loop through the values from the table to get the values from textbox and on click it should iterate over each value..the values are from databases

```
  var employeeList = JSON.stringify(text);
        var  hi = table.text;

        for (var i = 0; i < hi.length; i++) {
            //  var table = $("<table id=DynamicTable border=1></table>").appendTo("#employeeData");
            var employeeId = hi[i].employeeid;

            var employeeName = hi[i].name;
            var employeecity = hi[i].city;


            $('#tableemployees tbody').append('<tr><td>' + employeeId + '</td><td>' + employeeName + '</td><td>' + employeecity + '</td></tr>');

            $('td').click(function () {


                $('td:nth-child(2)').replaceWith(function () {

                    return '<input type="text" id="txt"' + employeeId + ' value="' + $(this).text() + '"> </input>';


                });
            });
```

Comment: whats the problem here...put up the markup and what are you trying to do with nth-child(2)

Comment: i want to replace the td to textbox and from that textbox i wanna read all the values and display the textbox value

Comment: why do you want to replace a td with a textbox...td is part of table it has to be there ,may be you can consider appending a textbox in the td

Comment: yes ur rite and from that textbox i should display each value

Comment: can you please provide your markup...it helps to solve the problem

Comment: added the problem

Comment: Modified the code...just check and let me know if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not the right one for adding rows dynamically
Another thing, you have mentioned you just want to display all the text box values which are in a td,but your code does not show that

You are replacing a td with text box ,which is wrong, td should always be in a table.

I am guessing you want a text box within a table td and on the click of that textbox you want to display that value

check the following code snippet

```js
var employeeList =[
   
   {"employeeid":"10","name":"xyz","city":"abc"},
   
   {"employeeid":"20","name":"xyz1","city":"abc1"},
 ];
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#submit").click(Submit);
  var employeeTable=$("#tableemployees");
 // alert(employeeList.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < employeeList.length; i++) {
    var empObject=employeeList[i];
    var row=$("<tr>");
     for (var prop in empObject) {
      
        
       var cell=$("<td>");
       if(prop==="name")
       {
        var text=$("<input type='text' id="+prop+">");
        text.val(empObject[prop]);
       text.appendTo(cell);
       
       }
       else 
         cell.html(empObject[prop]);
       cell.appendTo(row);
       row.appendTo(employeeTable);
    }
  }
});

function Submit(){
  var textBoxes=$('#tableemployees tbody tr td input');
  textBoxes.each(function(key){
     console.log($(textBoxes[key]).val());
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableemployees" >
 
    
</table>

<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>
```

I have also used dummy employee object
Hope this helps
Few suggestions

1.your code is not following naming conventions properly, dont use variable names like "hi"

2. Your search $("#tableemployees") again and again in the for loop. DOM search is costly ,use it catiously.You can store this in variable out of the loop and use that within

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you and the values i m getting s from database and from that i should display it into table format and then i should make it as textbox(only name cloumn) and then i should display the values which are der in textbox

Comment: thank you,but my requirement something like this,i should loop into the textbox and should display the each value on alert window..

Comment: ok you should loop into the text box not on td...am i correct

Comment: I have modified the code...now looping only the textboxes in the table and getting those values

Comment: i have attached click event to all the textboxes which are on the tbody and alerting those values. i am trying to do $("table tbody td input"), this returns an array of textboxes which are on the table and then i am binding an event which is nothing but looping each textbox

Comment: i hope you understand

Comment: yes, but how i bind it with onclick submit button and get the values using the loop

Comment: can you be clear here...do you want a submit button on which you want to access these textbox values

Comment: Modified the code...I have added a submit button ,on click of it ,im trying to access all the values of textboxes  which are present in the table

Comment: Let me know if it helped you

Comment: yes thank you and now the final question,instead of taking the submit from html how do we make it using jquery not using html ?

Comment: Do you mean you need a submit button to be added dynamically

Comment: Hey if you are fine with the solution ....Please consider accepting the answer :)